# Joomla using bootstrap (mod_bootstrapnav) menu issue

Tags: joomla-2.5, menu

I'm a beginner with joomla. In fact its my first website using it.

Ok, so I added a module ([mod_bootstrapnav](https://github.com/joomdigi/mod_bootstrapnav)) so I can use my menu with bootstrap. It is working fine, the problem is that I have a sub menu of a sub menu and it doesn't display correctly.

Take this example as menu:

`- Home
- About 1
- - About 2
- - - About 3 
- Contact`

So, I have `About 3` inside `About 2` which is inside `About 1`

It displays fine the `About 2` when I dont add the `3rd`. When I add `About 3` what happens is that `About 2` displays into the Main Menu, basically it displays like the above:

`- Home
- About 1
- - About 2
- About 2
- - About 3 
- Contact`

For some reason `About 2` goes outside displaying as parent.

What is the problem? Anyone experienced this?

Comment: I've never heard of this extension, and it sounds like it's a problem that is specific to the CSS or JS that it uses.  Your best best is going to be go to the developer with this, or at least provide some code for us to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap and this module do not support three levels.

You can check it in Bootstrap v2.3.2, navbar dropdowns definition: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns